# Flutter doesn't recognize Chrome as "web" or vice versa

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome, web

I am wondering why Flutter recognizes this command:

```
flutter build web
```

but it stutters when I run:

```
flutter run -d web
```

like so:

[image]

the "error" of course being

> No supported devices found with name or id matching 'web'.

just a suboptimal human experience and wondering why it had to be me this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web is not a device. If you want to run on chrome you should use

```
flutter run -d chrome
```